# Earned cards never show up in my deck

Tags: hearthstone

I am new to Hearthstone, but I am building up a Mage character all the way to level 10. At the end of many practice rounds, I have been granted additional cards for that character, like "Frost Nova".

However, I have played many subsequent games as the Mage, but these cards that I won, never ever show up. I have never had a card show up that lets me Freeze anything, even though I have won several such cards. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you playing with the premade Mage deck? You need to make your own deck to use the unlocked cards.

Comment: Shameless self-plug: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152573/how-are-basic-decks-built-in-hearthstone

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The basic decks only contain the cards you start with. When you unlock cards from leveling up, they aren't automatically added. You need to build a new deck containing those cards.

To do this, go to "My Collection" and click "New Deck".

Comment: Wow!  Okay.  Sounds like a basic solution.  The game's learning mechanics hadn't ever mentioned this deck-building capability from what I've seen.  Thanks!

Comment: They really need to make this "feature" more visible even all card games have a building deck feature if people have trouble finding them its no good

Comment: Yeah, if every upvote is someone who benefited from or would have benefited from this answer...

Answer (score 8):

They are in your collection. You have to make a deck that includes those cards.

There are preconstructed decks for every character, which is what you are using.

Comment: Sounds like I missed something basic!  This wasn't communicated to me via the game's tutorials and learning mechanics.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @blaster Yeah unfortunately it makes a few assumptions that the player knows how card games work, which clearly, not everyone does

Comment: Hell, I've played MtG for years and it never occurred to me that I had to manually update my deck for every card as part of the tutorial (first 10 levels). I did a /facepalm when I read it mentioned offhandedly a few months later.